# trim input from reg query

Tags: powershell, registry

Windows XP machine:

```
reg query "\\COMPUTER_NAME\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon" /v DefaultUserName
```

output of: `DefaultUserName    REG_SZ    ajstepanik`

.

Windows 7 machine

```
reg query "\\COMPUTER_NAME\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI" /v LastLoggedOnUser
```

output of: `LastLoggedOnUser    REG_SZ    GHS_NTDOMAIN\ajstepanik`

.

.

I was wondering if it were possible to trim this down so I would be left with `GHS_NTDOMAIN\ajstepanik`  ... or even better, if I could just get the username which in this example, is `ajstepanik`

The reason for pulling the name and storing it, is that I can take that and plug it into other commands.

.

.

EDIT for additional help (win7):

```
$reg1  = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $tag1)
$key1  = $reg1.OpenSubKey('Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI')
$user1 = $key1.GetValue('LastLoggedOnUser') -replace '^.*?\\'

echo $user1
```

returns error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\ajstepanik\Desktop\test.ps1:30 char:1
+ $user1 = $key1.GetValue('LastLoggedOnUser') -replace '^.*?\\'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: You're getting that error, because `OpenSubKey()` cannot find the registry path you specified, so `$key1` becomes `$null`. The correct path is `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\...`, not just `Microsoft\Windows\...`.

Comment: Yeah that seemed to work. Not sure why I left it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd drop `reg.exe` entirely and read the remote registry like this:

```
$rhost = 'COMPUTER_NAME'

$reg  = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $rhost)
$key  = $reg.OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon')
$user = $key.GetValue('DefaultUserName') -replace '^.*?\\'
```

It's a cleaner approach, since `GetValue` already produces the actual value. You don't have to parse it out of some other string before you can do things with it.

Comment: That one worked for windows xp, but for windows 7, I tried changing the path and everything but didnt get the same results.

Comment: @Aaron There are several things that may be getting in the way. Some I remember off the top of my head: `RemoteRegistry` service not running, Windows Firewall blocking connections, or different network classification (Home/Work/Domain/Public). Without a more detailed description of how exactly the results were different, there isn't much I could do to help.

Comment: I see in your third line you used "LocalMachine" for the xp registry path. Do you know if this is different in some way in 7 which is why its not working right? If you look at my 2 examples, it goes to lists localmachine differently so I am thinking the path is just entered wrong. Example: winxp=HKLM , win7=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: HKLM is just an abbreviation for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. Both refer to the same registry hive, and so does `'LocalMachine'`. You could also use `OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, $rhost)`, the result would be the same. Please stop guessing and start providing information. What is the result you get? And how is it different from the result you expect? What are you trying to achieve in the first place? You do realize that the two registry values you query don't hold the same information, don't you?

Comment: Changed the paths around to the win7 registry location and edited original post to show the error I got.

Answer (score 1):

Seems simple enough:

```
(reg query "\\%tag%\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI" /v LastLoggedOnUser).split('\')[1]
```

It's giving you back a string. Just split it at the backslash. and take the second element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft .NET Framework types to query the registry remotely, and get an object result. Check out the Remote Registry module for PowerShell: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PSRemoteRegistry

That being said, you can parse the output of your command above, like so:

```
$Output = reg query "\\%tag%\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI" /v LastLoggedOnUser
$Output -join '' -match '\w+\\\w+$';
$matches[0];
```

If you want to take it one step further, you can parse the domain and username via regex "named groups" like so:

```
$output -join '' -match '(?<domain>\w+)\\(?<username>\w+)$';
$matches.username;
$matches.domain;
```